# ntile function based on values and not counts

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get 5 percentiles , based on the summation of one column divided into 5 equal parts (the count of people in the percentiles should not be the same)

I tried running the ntile function but it got me the ntile based on counts

```
select name, data_usg, 
NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY data_usg asc) AS Quartile_data
from 
dev_TECH_KPIS
```

my table looks like this

```
Name    Data_usg
A         100
B         150
C         200
D         130
E         80
F         50
G         60
H         15
I         80
J         90
K         50
L         60
M         30
M         20
```

The end result would be allocating the names into cohorts and every cohort will have total data usage 1115/5=223.

Answer (score 0):

There are window functions for this sort of thing . . . such as `percentile_()` functions.  However, I prefer to do the calculation manually:

```
select dtk.*,
       floor(running_data_usg / (total_data_usg + 1)) as quintile
from (select dtk.*, sum(data_usg) over () as total_data_usg,
             sum(data_usg) over (order by data_usg asc) as running_data_usg
      from dev_TECH_KPIS dtk
     ) dtk;
```

I find that the manual calculation is almost as simple as using a single function (two functions rather than one).  But it gives much more control over handling ties and tweaks to the definition of percentile.